# iOS app can't find with search in app store but can found with link form iTune with app id

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

I have problem about my app.

I can't find app with search in app store even am search with full name of app. At first I think app is not appear in app store because is delay but I can find and download the app in app store with open link form menu "View on App Store" in iTuneConnect.

How I can fix this or I should to contact apple.

EDIT
Finally my app is show in app store with search.
Solution is just contact the apple.

Comment: How much time have you waited? First releases can take several hours to appear in the search engine, but less than a day.

Comment: App is appear after I releases 18 hour (appear in app store with link form menu View on App Store in iTuneConnect) now is 37 hour after releases app is still not show from searching (search with app name) in App Store

Answer (score 1):

I have faced a similar issue a while ago. Something happens with search engine. I found a tricky workaround and it worked for me. Idea is to change any app metadata and save it and revert it back after and save it. And app was available with in hours after that.

I did the following.

1. Removed the Privacy Policy, save it and reverted it back and save it.
   `iTunesConnect -> YOUR_APP -> App Information`
2. Removed 1 available territories (countries), save it and then added it back and save it.
   `iTunesConnect -> YOUR_APP -> Pricing & Availability -> Availability`

It worked for me Hopefully it will work for you.

Comment: Am try this solution about 3 hour ago. It's still not showing from search. Thank you sir.